# Terraform AWS ALB listener rule path

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm trying to set up a listener rule on my ALB that should route the `/api` path to a specified Target Group but for some reason I can't seem to get this to work.

This is my set up:

```
resource "aws_lb" "main" {
  name               = "${var.name}-alb-internal-${var.environment}"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  security_groups    = var.alb_security_groups
  subnets            = var.subnets.*.id

  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.name}-alb-${var.environment}"
    Environment = var.environment
  }
}

resource "aws_alb_target_group" "api" {
  name        = "${var.name}-tg-api-${var.environment}"
  port        = 8080
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id
  target_type = "ip"

  health_check {
    healthy_threshold   = "3"
    interval            = "30"
    protocol            = "HTTP"
    matcher             = "200"
    timeout             = "3"
    path                = var.health_check_path
    unhealthy_threshold = "2"
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_lb.main,
  ]

  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.name}-tg-api-${var.environment}"
    Environment = var.environment
  }
}

resource "aws_alb_listener" "api" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.main.id
  port              = 80
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type            = "fixed-response"

    fixed_response {
      status_code   = "404"
      content_type  = "text/plain"
      message_body  = "Hello world"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_alb_listener_rule" "api_rule" {
  listener_arn = aws_alb_listener.api.arn
  priority     = 100

  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.api.arn
  }

  condition {
    path_pattern {
      values = ["/api/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

In this set up I'm trying to forward every requests that starts with `/api` to my API target group. I have set up a fixed response as the default action for my listener and I have made the response body "Hello world" on purpose to differentiate.

My API service (that runs in ECS) returns `Forbidden` when `GET /` is performed. So, if the listener rule works I would expect that visiting `*.elb.amazonaws.com/api` would return `Forbidden`. However, these are the results I'm getting:

`*.elb.amazonaws.com/` -> `Hello World` (correct)

`*.elb.amazonaws.com/api` -> `Hello World` (expecting "Forbidden", i.e. the response of the root path of my API service)

`*.elb.amazonaws.com/api/health` -> `Not Found` (expecting "OK", the `/health` path exists on my API ECS service and return `200`)

I have successfully tested that my ECS API service works correctly by not using the listener rule and have the listener default action directly go to my Target Group.

How can I successfully forward any `/api` requests with my listener rule to my Target Group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your setup. I think all works as expected:

- '/' works as expected. Nothing unusual here.
- `/api` will default to `/`, so you will see "Hello World" as you are observing.
- `/api/health` will require on your ecs service `/api/health`, not `/health`. So if your ECS does not have `/api/health`, you will get `Not Found`.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. From your last point I get the impression that this listener rule is not really doing a forwarding (as e.g. Nginx does with a proxy pass) but that it's more a "mapping"... This means that my ECS service actually need to be configured with the same base path as in the listener rule for this to actually work correctly...

Comment: @Luke I don't think you can perform complex redirections as you can on nginx.